# How to change Eclipse help open modes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse in order to change the Eclipse Help Open Modes I normally have to go through:

> Window->Preferences->Help->Open Modes->Open Help Search

But let's say I want to do this in a program, as in, when I run a program it will change in the Preferences, in the Help Open Mode, from "In a browser" to "In the dynamic help view".

Are there any classes or methods implemented in the IWorkbench maybe that might do this? Or how else can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to set the preference value.

The preference dialog uses this code:

```
IEclipsePreferences pref = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode(HelpBasePlugin.PLUGIN_ID);

pref.put(IHelpBaseConstants.P_KEY_HELP_VIEW_OPEN_MODE, mode);

pref.flush();
```

where 'mode' is `IHelpBaseConstants.P_IN_BROWSER` or `IHelpBaseConstants.P_IN_EDITOR` or `IHelpBaseConstants.P_IN_PLACE.

**But** `HelpBasePlugin` and `IHelpBaseConstants` are internal classes so should not be used. All the values are strings so you could code them directly - but there is no guarantee the values will not change in future.

Comment: Interesting, but P_KEY_HELP_VIEW_OPEN_MODE is for "Open help view documents" while I'm trying to change the "Open help search". I took a look in IHelpBaseConstants and I did found P_KEY_SEARCH_FROM_BROWSER which works for changing from the "In a browser" to "In the dynamic help view". Unfortunately it only goes one way. If do this: pref.put(IHelpBaseConstants.P_KEY_SEARCH_FROM_BROWSER, "anything"); it will move my help search preference to "In the dynamic help view". Any idea on how I might get back to "In Browser" from there?